# Local web storing of files using HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, google-gears, offlineapps

I was fascinated by [Google Gears](http://gears.google.com/) and its potential use in online game development, particularly massive online game development. One could take the game resources and store them locally using [ResourceStore](http://code.google.com/apis/gears/api_localserver.html#ResourceStore), thus reducing game load time, server bandwidth issues, etc. I have therefore welcomed the news that HTML5 supports offline storage.

However, from what I can tell it only supports [a manifest file for resource caching](http://www.w3.org/TR/offline-webapps/), which looks like something [ManagedResourceStore](http://code.google.com/apis/gears/api_localserver.html#ManagedResourceStore) is supposed to offer. I didn't study either in detail.

I also didn't find something that would allow programatically loading resources and caching them (as apparently ResourceStore allows).

Is it possible to programatically control which resources should be cached? Or would I have to store each "map" on a separate page with separate manifest file (with this being in fact done through a server side script, instead of literally creating pages and manifests -- this is still fugly)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking about design work, it seems like you're looking for [Programmable HTTP Caching and Serving](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/DataCache/). If you actually wanted to know if there's something like this in shipping browsers, then I don't know, but doubt it.

Comment: From skimming through this a bit, it does seem to be what I'm looking for. I sincerely hope someone ships with this; if not now, then in nearby future. Thank you!